# Bootstrap align-items-end but without the columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I need to align the elements inside a div to the end. And as I understand from Bootstrap's documentation, I should use d-flex and align-items-end. When I apply it, it sticks the elements to the bottom, but it also splits them into columns. And I don't want that.

What do I need to do to fix it?

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-5">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body text-left d-flex align-items-end">
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Link</a>
        <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Text goes here</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: by 'end' you mean to the right of the div?

Comment: I mean at the bottom of the div?

Comment: shouldn't the class be 'card-block' not card-body?

Comment: Not according to Bootstrap 4 documentation.

Comment: You mean they should stack vertical, but bottom aligned?

Comment: Exactly. I want them to be bottom aligned but not split into columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To stack elements on top of each other, use `flex-column`, and for *column* items to align at bottom, you need to use `justify-content-end` instead of `align-items-end`.

*Note, the horizontal misalignment is caused by the different class set on the `a`/`h5`/`p` elements.*

Stack snippet

```css
.card {
  height: 300px;      /*  just for this demo, so one can see how it aligns 
 */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-5">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body text-left d-flex flex-column justify-content-end">
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Link</a>
        <a href="#" class="card-link">Link</a>
        <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
        <p class="card-text">Text goes here</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome, just one more question. How do I, with this layout, keep the two card-links inlined?

Comment: Nevermind. Figured it out. Just added d-inline and wrapped them in a div. Will accept this as an answer as soon as SO lets me! Thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is to do this:

1. Add the classes `d-flex flex-column` to the `card-body` div.
2. Add the `mt-auto` class (margin-top:auto) to the first item.

That will now push the first item and everything that follows to the bottom.

Using this method allows you to have **better control** of the elements inside. So, if tomorrow you decide that only the last 2 elements should stick to the bottom, you can just move the `mt-auto` class to the second to last element. So, it gives you a bit **more flexibility**.

Here's a working code snippet (click the "run code snippet" button below to check) and notice that I've added `min-height: 333px;` inline to demonstrate that it works:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-5">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body text-left d-flex flex-column" style="min-height: 333px;">
                    <a href="#" class="card-link mt-auto">Link</a>
                    <a href="#" class="card-link">Link</a>
                    <h5 class="card-title">Title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">Text goes here</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>
                    <a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```